# How is the .toString() overloaded in the Arrays class

Tags: java, overriding, overloading, tostring

I came across the concept where a method cannot be overridden and overloaded at the same time. But when I used Arrays.toString(),
[image: image1]

Correct me if I'm wrong, but the toString() method has been overridden and overloaded at the same time. How is that possible?

Comment: No, `Arrays` doesn't have a `toString` method without arguments, so nothing is overridden here.

Comment: You're wrong. You can create a class which overrides `toString()` (note, no parameters) and overload `toString` with parameters.

Comment: Btw, in general a method can have several overloaded versions, each of which may also be overrides, or be overridden in turn; so I don't think "cannot be overridden and overloaded at the same time" is very clear in what it means. But the Arrays method are static, so overriding does not even enter the picture.

Comment: @MCEmperor @user7 thanks. I understood.
@khelwood. I'm sorry if my question was not clear but what I meant by "cannot be overriden and overloaded at the same time"  was is there a way to override a method and then overload it. For eg. I'm overriding the .hashcode() method in `MyClass` class and can I overload it in now.

Comment: Why would you want to overload hashCode()? The use relies on any given object having  single hashcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding when you have the exact same method signature in a subclass. You are overloading when you have two equal named methods with different type or number of parameters. You can override a method and then overload it but you can write a method and it can happend that when you overload it you end up overriding a super class method. One thing doesn't exclude the other.

Let's have a Super class like this:

```
public class Super {

    public void testMethod() {}

    // Overload
    public void testMethod(String param) {}
}
```

And then extend it with a sub class like this:

```
public class Sub extends Super {

    // Override only
    @Override
    public void testMethod() {}

    // Overload only
    public void testMethod(int param) {}

    // Overload and Override
    @Override
    public void testMethod(String param) {}
}
```

As you can see, you can have only overload, only override or both in multiple ways. As said, one thing doesn't exclude the other.